# SQL Where clause pass list to a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some table `DOCUMENTS` that have a column `TYPE_ID` and a table named `TYPES`
Now I want to make a query which filter on my `DOCUMENTS` all the document that have a list of `TYPE_ID` that can be a single element or sort of elements

The normal query is:

```
Select * From DOCUMENTS Where TYPE_ID = myValue
```

But when it can be a list of known elements the wuery looks like

```
Select * From DOCUMENTS Where TYPE_ID = myValue1 or TYPE_ID = myValue2 or TYPE_ID = myValue3
```

But if you have n elements.... how can this query be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `IN` Clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM  Documents 
WHERE Type_ID IN (myValue1, myValue2, myValue3)
```

As a side note, if you're new to this clause you **cannot do** something like :

```
@myVar = '1,2,3'
select * FROM Documents where Type_ID in (@myVar)
```

There are solutions for something like this.  But I point it out because it seems to come up when people are new to the IN clause.